# When would you use an Ink on a Tamiya 1:48 scale aircraft kit?

Tags: material-selection

When painting a Tamiya 1:48 scale WWII plastic P51B aircraft kit, which parts would you use an Ink on, rather than paint or a wash in order to replicate the picture on the box for the following component

Cockpit interior
Cockpit canopy
Wings
Fusalage
Guns
Control surfaces
Armament
Pilot
Landing gear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138879/discussion-on-question-by-aaargh-zombies-when-would-you-use-an-ink-on-a-tamiya-1).

Answer (score 4):

First let's look at the definition of some products and techniques used in model painting:

**Ink** is pigment suspended in a liquid (low viscosity) medium. It can achieve a solid, opaque coverage in a very thin layer, thereby preserving the small details of the miniature. There are some transparent inks, but the default for miniature painting is opaque. As usual, low quality inks may also be translucent because of a lower pigment content.

**Paint** is usually also opaque, but suspended in a thicker (high viscosity) medium. Depending on the quality (pigment content) you may need a thicker layer to achieve a solid, opaque color, but high quality paints usually can be thinned down to a much more liquid and ink-like consistency and still be opaque.

**Wash, Shade or Glaze** originally describes a technique rather than a product, but several companies sell products they call by those names. A wash is a very liquid, very thinned down dark (traditionally dark brown or grey) paint or ink that is applied on top of already painted areas. It's supposed to flow into recesses and leave more pigments there, creating a shadow effect. A shade is pretty much the same as a wash, just in other colors. A glaze is either ink or paint that is very thinned down with a viscous medium to create a transparent paint that doesn't flow into recesses like a wash or shade would.

The **advantage** of an ink is the intense color and very quick, opaque coverage of big areas. You could use it as a base layer before adding highlights and shadows.
The **disadvantage** is that their high pigment content can quickly overwhelm underlying paints, which makes them hard to mix wet-in-wet. They also don't behave well on a wet palette and dry quicker than acrylic paints. If you wanted to use an ink for dry brushing, you would first need to dilute it with a viscous acrylic medium, practically creating a paint from an ink. Most inks have a glossy finish.

A very good comparison can be found in [this post by Tangible Day](https://tangibleday.com/wash-ink-and-shade-whats-the-difference/).

As for realistic scenarios:

- I would use an ink as a base color for my miniatures, especially if I have several miniatures of similar color like skin color, uniforms, banners or cloaks.
- I would use an ink to add a highlight of a stark contrast on top of other paint layers. For example, if you want to add a white or yellow highlight on top of a black base coat, you might need a thicker layer of paint, but you can achieve the same with a thin layer of ink.
- I would use paints for most of the painting and especially blending colors. (Mostly because I love using a wet palette, but also because it's easier to create color transitions).
- I would use paints for dry brushing.
- I would thin down either paint or ink of the desired color to create a wash. Ink is harder to use because a tiny amount can quickly overwhelm other colors.

I'd say you can easily paint miniatures with paints only, but it's harder to do if you only have inks.

Comment: True ink is pigment in a suspension, not paint in a solution; it looks like there's terminology in miniature paints that confuses the matter, as it seems that by "ink" what is actually meant is "opaque paint wash," not "pigment in suspension intended to penetrate the surface when applied." Some terminology clarification might be worthwhile, since I was considering a portion of this answer incorrect until I clicked through to the reference page.

Comment: @AllisonC You're right, that was a poor choice of words.